# Distinct Count behavior with Blank Spaces

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Please consider the following:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#CharacterTest') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #CharacterTest

CREATE TABLE #CharacterTest
(
  [ID] int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
[CharField] varchar(50) NULL 
)


INSERT INTO #CharacterTest (CharField)
VALUES ('DavidIsCool.')
      , ('David')
      , ('Bleh')
      , ('Bleh')
      , ('A')
      , ('A')
      , (' ')
      , ('  ')
      , ('   ')
      , ('    ')
      , ('       ');


Select count(*) RecordCount from  #CharacterTest
SELECT DISTINCT CharField FROM #CharacterTest
SELECT count (DISTINCT CharField) FROM #CharacterTest
```

For the second and third queries, I get a total of 5 values returned.

Why do my queries indicate that the records entirely composed of spaces are equal? Is this due to a collation setting?

Comment: Anyway even if you create the table with `SET ANSI_PADDING ON;` you can't get the right results unless you also do something else with the string. e.g. `SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT CharColumn + '.') ...`. This doesn't work if `ANSI_PADDING` was off when the table was created (and also might have funny results if you have strings that are 49 or 50 characters long). You should never be using `SET ANSI_PADDING OFF;` - it has been deprecated for some time now.

Comment: Aaron, To be honest, it's an academic exercise. I'm working on something and noticed the behavior. I wanted to be able to explain the behavior but Google searches proved fruitless, so I asked.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't being critical, I was curious if there was a real reason they needed to be deemed different.

Answer (score 2):

Never realized this before, but [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626) is your answer...

> SQL Server follows the ANSI/ISO SQL-92 specification (Section 8.2,
>   , General rules #3) on how to compare strings
>   with spaces. The ANSI standard requires **padding for the character
>   strings used in comparisons so that their lengths match before
>   comparing them.**

Also from the same article, regarding my initial failed assumption that this was due to the ANSI_PADDING setting:

> The SET ANSI_PADDING setting does not affect whether SQL Server pads
>   strings before it compares them. SET ANSI_PADDING only affects whether
>   trailing blanks are trimmed from values being inserted into a table,
>   so it affects storage but not comparisons.

Comment: @AaronBertrand To get the correct count, you can do something like... SELECT count (DISTINCT CharField + 'x') FROM #CharacterTest

Comment: @AaronBertrand Not sure what your problem is, I was just answering your question.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I realize deleting requires a refresh and most people don't, which is why I advised you to do so.  I didn't mean for that to be offensive, although I was a little taken aback by you setting the tone with your sarcastic "That's great...".  The second answer wasn't incomplete, he didn't ask the question that you added.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29138/discussion-between-kekekela-and-aaron-bertrand)

Comment: "Do you think someone with 75K has difficulty comprehending how the site works? " ... Apparently.

Comment: I think its a reasonable follow-up, but not implicit.  He was confused as to why he was seeing the behavior that he was seeing, once you understand the "why" its not to difficult to figure out the "how".

Comment: Its not incomplete, as the questioner pointed out when you proffered the supposedly lacking information, he just wanted to be able to explain the behavior.

Comment: Right, so you're not missing any information about how the table got into this situation, or why ANSI_PADDING actually *is* relevant (just not in the way you stated in your other, deleted answer)? Ok.

Comment: How the table got into the situation is irrelevant.  The relevant information about ANSI_PADDING is included.  I also pointed out that my initial assumption about ANSI_PADDING off was not what was causing this.

Comment: Ok, if you say so. *shrug*